# How do I add months to a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I add months to the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in SQL Server?

The solution probably lies in DATEADD() but this works with a date only, not a datetime.

Thanks.

Comment: DATEADD() works with Datetime ...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This works perfectly fine

```
SELECT DATEADD(month,1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

From [DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

> date
>
> Is an expression that can be
>   resolved to a time, date,
>   smalldatetime, datetime, datetime2, or
>   datetimeoffset value.

Comment: Tried it again and it works... there must have been something wrong somewhere else in the query. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The Current_Timestamp is the ansi equivalent of GetDate() in SQL, so it is perfetly acceptable to use within a DateAdd function.

```
select dateadd(m,3,current_timestamp)
```

Adds 3 months to the current timestamp.

Answer (score -1):

`add_months(Tablename,No.of months)`