# Add time to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I made the mistake of being born in New Zealand and now have to work out how to add 15 hours onto my server time! Would appreciate any ideas.

At the moment I'm using:

```
mysql_query("
INSERT INTO articles (Id, DateAdded)
VALUES ('" . $currentid . "', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
");
```

I'm thinking it's related to [How do I add months to a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424110/how-do-i-add-months-to-a-current-timestamp-in-sql).

Have tried `DATEADD(month,1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` to no avail in place of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: My condolences. Have you tried setting your timezones correctly?

Comment: Do you mean server-wide? If so, I'm using a lame shared server which doesn't let you change server timezones.

Comment: Don't forget about daylight savings! Might also be a problem if your host also observes daylight savings and they overlap with NZ DST.

Comment: excellent point @row1 - I'm sure this will be very relevant in most applications, but for mine I'm only ever outputting the date (without the time) so an hour here or there isn't the end of the world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this problem it's best if you [change the server's timezone](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html).

Also, a better way is to set the server's timezone to UTC (or GMT-0) and then translate all dates on the UI layer. That way you can have a global application which will be correctly displaying the dates to all users (think gmail). For this you'll of course need a timezone preference for each user.

If you cannot permanently change the timezone on the server (because you are on a shared hosting) then you'll need to be setting the timezone every time you connect to the database using the following query:

```
SET time_zone = '-8:00';
```

Finally, to do time arithmetic you can try:

```
addtime(current_timestamp, '15:00')
```

Comment: Thanks @cherouvim. Alas, I'm pretty sure my only access to MySQL is via PHPMyAdmin. I'm using a pretty basic shared Dreamhost account.

Comment: any way to do the above for the default value of a field which's type is TIME STAMP?