# SQL date within a specific range

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, and if we have 2 dates, how to return those records having the first date within 6 months before the second date. For example in the following table:

[image]

The output will be the highlighted rows in green.

Please note that I'm not trying to calculate the difference between a date from my table and te current date.

Comment: use datediff function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add months to a CURRENT\_TIMESTAMP in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424110/how-do-i-add-months-to-a-current-timestamp-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATEDIFF

```
select date1,date2
from mytable
where datediff(month,date1,date2) < 7
```